Track a process across multiple functions
I have a function app which is being consumed - one of these end points is a http trigger which someone can call - it fetches some data from another API and I need to store the data returned into a data store and then return the data to the caller. Let's call this the retrieve function.
I am planning on extracted the "data store" section of this to a queue for another function within the app to pick up and handle. Ie add the data to a queue and have a function watch the queue and its then responsible for adding that into the data store. Let's call this the save function.
Now I want to add some traceability to this and this is what I need some guidance on.
I plan to add the invocation id to the header that gets returned on the retrieve function so the caller can add this to their records so we can directly link the call to a run on the function. What I'd like to try and achieve is a full log of the entire process - so a way to link the retrieve to the save function - ie this retrieve function triggered this queue which was picked up by the function.
Some sort of correlation id to show all actions / runs that happened and was spurred from the original call.
How might this be achieved?

Use the Correlation ID to link/track requests across different functions. By passing the ID through each function call, you can correlate logs and telemetry data to a specific workflow instance
